# Android File Upload Working Inconsistently

Tags: php, android, heroku

I am trying to upload some data to a Heroku/PHP server and for some reason it's working inconsistently. It works perfectly fine for me at our office, but when others try to use our app no file ever reaches the server. The server gives an "empty file" error.

Here is the upload code from Android:

```
private class SubmitClientTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    AlertDialog.Builder mDialog;
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ClientSignActivity.this);
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        //int count = urls.length;
            long totalSize = 0;
            String response = "";
            File signatureFile = new File(signaturePhotoPath);
            File photoFile = new File(StaticValues.currentPhotoPath);
            String boundary = "*****";//Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis());
            String CRLF = "\r\n";
            String charset = "UTF-8";
            try {
                URLConnection mConnection = urls[0].openConnection();
                mConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                ((HttpURLConnection)mConnection).setRequestMethod("POST");
                //mConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive"); // would this line of code help?
                mConnection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); // this one?
                mConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

                OutputStream output = mConnection.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, charset));

                writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
                writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"dentistName\"").append(CRLF);
                writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(CRLF);
                writer.append(CRLF).append("A string here").append(CRLF).flush();

                writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
                writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"patientName\"").append(CRLF);
                writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(CRLF);
                writer.append(CRLF).append("Another string here").append(CRLF).flush();

                writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
                writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"patientPhone\"").append(CRLF);
                writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(CRLF);
                writer.append(CRLF).append("A third string").append(CRLF).flush();

                //set up image stuff
                InputStream is;
                int c;
                byte[] buf;

                //send image
                writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
                writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"patientPhoto\"; filename=\"" + photoFile.getName() + "\"").append(CRLF);
                writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(CRLF);
                writer.append(CRLF).flush();
                c = 0;
                is = new FileInputStream(StaticValues.patientBitmapToSend);
                buf = new byte[8192];
                while ((c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
                    output.write(buf, 0, c);
                    output.flush();
                }
                output.flush();
                writer.append(CRLF).flush();

                //send another photo
                writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
                writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"signaturePhoto\"; filename=\"" + signatureFile.getName() + "\"").append(CRLF);
                writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(CRLF);
                writer.append(CRLF).flush();
                c = 0;
                is = new FileInputStream(signatureFile);
                buf = new byte[8192];
                while ((c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
                    output.write(buf, 0, c);
                    output.flush();
                }
                output.flush();
                writer.append(CRLF).flush();

                //end of multipart/form-data
                writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(CRLF).flush();
                Log.d("content: ", mConnection.getContent().toString());
                int responseCode = ((HttpURLConnection) mConnection).getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    String line;
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mConnection.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        response += line;
                    }
                    sendStuffResponse = response;
                } else {
                    response = "failed";

                }

                //finally,
                Log.d("Response: ", response);

                ((HttpURLConnection) mConnection).disconnect();

                //cleanup
                (new File(StaticValues.currentPhotoPath)).delete();
                photoFile.delete();
                signatureFile.delete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return totalSize;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        //setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        progressDialog.dismiss();

        mDialog.setTitle(R.string.upload_success_title);
        mDialog.setMessage(R.string.upload_success_str); //DEBUG sendStuffResponse
        mDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_str, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
        mDialog.create().show();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloaded " + result + " bytes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }`. That catch block is empty. So if there is a catch how do you inform the user about it? At the moment not at all. So the user never knows if something went wrong. And you either.

Comment: Good point, I should add an error message, however I do know that no image reaches the server because I see that only 169 bytes made it and that the file was empty. It also gives a response code of 500.

Comment: Is the server only accessible from your internal network?  Is there a firewall between the outside network and yours?

Comment: The server is a heroku server. The app works just fine at home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. The script on the server was running before all the image data arrived.
Heroku is set up to directly send images to s3:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3